# Representation of a matrix as product of unitary matrices and diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $C=A+B$ where $A$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix and $B$ is a positive semi-definite skew symmetric matrix. Clearly $C$ is neither symmetric nor skew symmetric.Then is it possible to write $C=UDU^H$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix and $U$ is a unitary matrix even though it is not symmetric? If so can someone provide a proof for the same.

Comment: What do you mean by positive semi-definite? Positive semi-definitness includes as a part of the definition, that the matrix is symmetric, therefore "skew-symmetric positive semi-definite matrix" does not make really sense.

Comment: Presumably Ram is using a version of "positive semidefinite" that does not require a symmetric (real) or hermitian (complex) matrix.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible in general.  $N = U D U^H$ is a normal matrix, i.e. 
$N N^H = N^H N = U D D^H U^H$.  But e.g. 
$$ C = \pmatrix{2 & 0\cr 2 & 2\cr} = \pmatrix{2 & 1\cr 1 & 2\cr} + \pmatrix{0 & -1\cr 1 & 0\cr}$$
is the sum of a positive definite symmetric matrix and a positive semidefinite (in the sense that doesn't require hermitian) skew-symmetric matrix, but is not normal:
$$C C^H = \pmatrix{4 & 4\cr 4 & 8\cr} \ne C^H C = \pmatrix{8 & 4\cr 4 & 4\cr} $$